# Is it possible to fixed the sending port in MLLP application?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, port, mina

I have develop an application (MLLP server) which is sending and receiving HL7 messages. I can track the ip and port when receive messages. But when the client application restart the port will change. Same thing happen with my server also. When i am receiving message no problem, which port i have define it is working. But i can not set any sending port. Application will manage a port by itself. So, when my server is restart sending port also changing.
Please help me about this. Is it possible to fixed a single port for sending messages?
I am using Apache Camel, Mina2, SpringBoot.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Our client is only letting in traffic coming from a certain port and the random ports o startup seem to be causing us Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

When you are the server you do not care about the client-port. Just specify the port like this: `mina2:tcp://0.0.0.0:6001`

When you are the client there is also no need to specify the client port (it is selected by the library/operating system). Like `mina2:tcp://<hostname>:<port>`